# Не работает импорт установленной PySide6 в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, импорт, pyside6

У меня Windows 7 и Python 3.8.5

Установил PySide6 в терминале PyCharm при помощи команд:

Сперва

```
pip install PySide6
```

Потом всё удалил и установил через

```
pip3 install PySide6
```

В обоих случаях всё успешно устанавливалось

```
Successfully installed PySide6-6.4.0.1 PySide6-Addons-6.4.0.1 PySide6-Essentials-6.4.0.1 shiboken6-6.4.0.1
```

**Но когда пишу в коде программы**

```
import PySide
```

Появляется ошибка

```
No module named 'PySide'
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: `from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore`  ?

Comment: @S.Nick Unresolved reference 'PySide6/QtWidgets/QtGu/QtCore'. **РЕШИЛ** эту проблему скачав pyside так: File->Settings, сбоку Project: (имя проекта)->Python Interpreter, там нажимаем на плюсик, в поиске пишем нужный модуль и скачиваем. Теперь импорт работает, **но** при запуске: _ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: Не найдена указанная процедура_. Скорее всего это из-за windows 7.